# Save SKLearnProcessor transformer in sagemaker

Tags: python, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I wanted to use the [SKLearnProcessor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/sagemaker.sklearn.html#sagemaker.sklearn.processing.SKLearnProcessor) in Sagemaker to perform some transformations on an input dataset. However, I want to save this fitted transformer into Sagemaker to reuse it later in other scripts. How can I do that?. I don't see anywhere how it can be stored in S3 at least not in the SDK.